# list of one string element getting converted to list of characters

Tags: python-3.x, string, list

I have a program which receives input from another program and use it for further operations. The input can be a list, set, tuple but for further operations a list is needed. So I am converting input to list.

The problem arises when input my program receives is a list/set/tuple with just one element like below. The

```
import itertools


def not_mine(c):
    d = {'John':['mid', 'forward'],
         'Lana':['mid'],
         'Jacob':['defence', 'mid'],
         'Ian':['goal', 'mid']}

    n = itemgetter(*c)(d)
    n = list(set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(n)))

    return n

def mine(c):
    name = not_mine(c)
    name_1 = list(name)
    print(name_1)

mine(['Jacob', 'Ian'])
['defence', 'goal', 'mid']

mine(['Lana'])
['i', 'm', 'd']
```

Is there any way to prevent the second case? It should be a list of one element ['mid'].

Comment: `len(ip)  == 6` so I don't understand your claim that the input is of length 1. Could you explain?

Comment: @a_guest that was by mistake, edited it. I meant I cannot use length comparison on the input.

Comment: Your input seems to be `ip`. In the above example `ip` is not of length 1. Hence I don't understand your question.

Comment: The program receives ip as an input and it can be a list/tuple/set of one element. When that happens, converting it to list using list(ip) converts it into list of individual characters. I do not want that.

Comment: But in your example `ip` is a `set` of **6** elements, so how does that relate to your question? Could you provide an example that supports your question together with expected output?

Comment: I have added a better example, it might help

Comment: You can check `len(c) > 1` and only then use `chain.from_iterable`.

Answer (score 0):

## Iterators

The function `set` uses the first argument as an iterator to create a sequence of items. `str` is natively an iterator. In other words, you can loop over a `str` and you'll assign to the for variable each character in the string per iteration.

```py
for whatami in "hi!":
    print(whatami)
```

```
h
i
!
```

If you want to treat a single string input as a single item, explicitly pass an iterator argument to set (`list` works the same way, BTW) with a single item in it. Tuple is, also, an iterator. Let's try to use it to prove our theory

```py
t1 = ('ourstring', )
print(f"t1 is of type {type(t1)}")
s1 = set(t1)
print(s1)
```

```
t1 is of type <class 'tuple'>
{'ourstring'}
```

It works!
What we've done with `('ourstring', )` is explicitly define a tuple with one item. There's a familiar delimiter, `,`, used to say "this tuple is instantiated with only one item".

## Input

To separate situations between ingesting a list of items and one string item, you can consider two approaches.
The most straight-forward way is to agree on a delimiter in the input such as comma separated values. `firstvalue,secondvalue,etc`. The down side of this is that you'll quickly run into limitations of what kind of data you can receive.

To ease your development, `argparse` is strongly recommended command line arguments. It is a built-in, battle-hardened package made for this type of task. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)'s first example even shows a multi-value field.

Comment: Well that is not in my control to instantiate the input correctly. I have to make do with whatever I get. If input is of one element tuple instantiated as ip = ('qwerty'), I have to use that only.

Comment: @Sim101011 Instantiation happens in your code. Either it's always a single item string or there's an indicator when there are multiple items. Such as spaces (if `argparse` is used) or commas (if you parse the input yourself).